# Error: npm is known not to run on Node.js V4.2.6

Tags: node.js, npm

how can I solve the following error? I use Ubuntu 16.
When I run any npm command such as "npm run dev" I get this error:

> ERROR: npm is known not to run on Node.js v4.2.6 Node.js 4 is
>   supported but the specific version you're running has a bug known to
>   break npm. Please update to at least ${rel.min} to use this version of
>   npm. You can find the latest release of Node.js at https://nodejs.org/

Comment: I don't know what to do with $(rel.min) ?

Comment: Is there anything stopping you installing the latest version?

Comment: Update to latest node version. Known error message.

Answer (score 58):

First, Uninstall completely nodejs and npm.

```
sudo apt remove nodejs npm
```

Then, reinstall it over the link below:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Refer: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Comment: It seems there's already `setup_9.x`. What is the preferred version?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka `setup_9.x` worked without any issues.

Answer (score 5):

You can try downgrading the node version to switch from the bugged version using the following, upgrading also works if your app supports latest versions.

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.4/install.sh | bash

nvm install 4.2.5

nvm use 4.2.5

//check with 
node -v

//To uninstall a node version 
nvm uninstall 4.2.6
```

Answer (score 3):

I just had this issue on Ubuntu 16. Use *n* to update to the latest version

```
sudo n latest
```

That should settle it.

Answer (score 2):

I download latest install package from https://nodejs.org/en/ and reinstall it. Solve it!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use NVM - I did this to solve the same problem.

first type

`nvm ls-remote` to view the latest versions available,

then

`nvm install [version]` (I used v8.7.0)

everything should be fine after that.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but my project is part of a bigger system so neither switching to nvm instead of npm nor upgrading my version of Node.js were options.

However, moving npm backwards to a previous version was an option. I found 4.6.1 worked without complaint.

```
sudo npm install -g npm@4.6.1
```

This version of npm did not complain.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same issue with Ubuntu 16.04 by using following commands step by step.

Uninstall nodejs and install version 8.0

```
$ sudo apt remove nodejs npm  
$ curl -o- 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
$ nvm install 8.0
$ nvm use 8.0
$ node -v
v8.0.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Get latest release with

```
$ nvm install node
```

Then run the following

```
$ nvm alias default stable_node_version
```