# nodejs 4.2.6 not getting updated to latest version

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

I installed Node and npm as they are required to install angular cli.
Now, if I type this command:

```
npm install -g angular-cli
```

I get this message in terminal:

> ERROR: npm is known not to run on Node.js v4.2.6 Node.js 4 is supported but the specific version you're running has a bug known to break npm. Please update to at least 4.7.0 to use this version of npm. You can find the latest release of Node.js at https://nodejs.org/

I also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360567/error-npm-is-known-not-to-run-on-node-js-v4-2-6) link, but still the issue is not resolved.

I tried removing node, npm and then reinstalling, updating node according to all the ways I found on internet, but still the version(4.2.6) is same.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong as I am new to Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly, `npm` is quite complicated in Linux, until you discover [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) which allows you to easily install new versions and swap between them.

After installing nvm, you can install any node version with `nvm install <VERSION_NUMBER>` and you can set it as default with `nvm alias default <VERSION_NUMBER>`

You can swap between versions using `nvm use <VERSION_NUMBER>`