# ERROR: npm is known not to run on Node.js v0.12.4

Tags: node.js

I am getting this error when I open my terminal on Ubuntu 16.

```
ERROR: npm is known not to run on Node.js v0.12.4
You'll need to upgrade to a newer version in order to use this
version of npm. Supported versions are 4, 6, 7, 8, 9. You can find the
latest version at https://nodejs.org/
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""
Run `nvm use --delete-prefix v0.12.4 --silent` to unset it.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The node version you are using should not run with the version of `node` you are using..
Can you change your node version?

Comment: I have remove node and nodejs from my system, I am still getting this error

Comment: how did you remove it? its an error with `nvm`

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360567/error-npm-is-known-not-to-run-on-node-js-v4-2-6

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan I followed this article to remove nodejs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x & this article: https://askubuntu.com/questions/786015/how-to-remove-nodejs-from-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: You have node.js installed separately or via `nvm`?